# Проблема в си с битовыми операциями

Tags: c, битовые-операции

подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью битовых операций в си можно записать условие `c == 0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3912112/3240681

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем такое нужно, но например -- `(с == с ^ c)`

Comment: Я не понимаю, разве допустимо использование при этом циклов, операторов равенствеа и прочих? Уточните задачу.

Comment: @avp Даже если можно использовать `==`, вы забыли о приоритетах операторов!

Comment: @Mikhailo, вы правы, `(c == (c ^ c))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
bool isZero(int x) {
  int val = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) * 8; i++) {
    val |= x & 1;
    x >>= 1;
  }
  return !val & 1;
}
```

Если в `x` есть хоть один ненулевой бит, то после цикла `val` будет равно 1, иначе 0. Потом инвертируем все биты у `val` и берем последний

Answer (score 0):

Условие `c == 0` означает `НЕ (с != 0)`.

Любое ненуклевое выражение при преобразовании в `bool` дает `true`, нулевое - `false`. Так что ваше `c` само по себе если нулевое, дает `false`, если нет - `true`. Чтобы было наобоорот - надо просто изменить его на обратное - написать `!c`.

Чисто битовыми - можно, но сложно, потому что надо подобрать такую последовательность операций, которая из 0 сделает ненулевое число (это просто), а из ЛЮБОГО ненулевого - ноль.

Comment: Из любого ноль это XOR само с собой

Comment: @avp Обратите внимание - у меня написано "из ЛЮБОГО ненулевого". Не "из любого".

Answer (score 0):

```
// gcc -std=c11 -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic uintis0.c
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <iso646.h>
# include <stddef.h>
bool  uint_is0  ( unsigned  int c ) {
  // узнаём количество битов в типе unsigned int
  size_t s = sizeof ( unsigned int  ) * 8U ;
  do {
    --  s ;
    if ( c bitand 1U )
      // если младший бит не ноль, тогда
      //  число точно не ноль
      return  false ;
    // переходим на следующий бит
    c >>= 1U ;
    // пока биты не закончаться
  } while ( s ) ;
  return  true  ; }
```

или просто без битов если можно :

```
  return ! c ;
```